# How to make an image : enlarge when small, keep center when large

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have a image container(a div) with a set width and height.

now I got an image url from the backend and I need to put it in the container.

when the image is smaller than the container, I need to enlarge it to fullfill the container
when the image is bigger than the container, I need to center it in the container.

could this be done in pure CSS? or do I need to use JavaScript to do something?

Comment: Sorry, totally commented on the wrong box. Can't you just give the image a width of 100%, so it will always be in the boundaries of the parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a mixture of css and javascript, here's an example I've created for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/7fUxw/1/

Answer (score 0):

What about `min-width:100px` on the image, where the div is a width of 100px.